# modelformset_factory and csrf token missing or incorrect

Tags: python, django, django-forms, formset

I am using model formsets to add multiple instances of a model at once. and I am using class based views. This is my views.py part for creating a "Library"

```
class LibraryCreate(View):
model = Library

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    LibraryFormSet = modelformset_factory(
        Library, form=create_library, extra=2)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = LibraryFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            # do something with the formset.cleaned_data
            pass
    else:
        formset = LibraryFormSet()
    return render_to_response(
        'trial1/library_form.html', {'formset': formset})

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    LibraryFormSet = modelformset_factory(
        Library, form=create_library, extra=2)
    formset = LibraryFormSet(queryset=Library.objects.none())
    return render_to_response(
        'trial1/library_form.html', {'formset': formset})
```

and this is my template

```
<form method="post" action="{% url "library_create" %}">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
<table>
    {% for form in formset %}
    {{ form }}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<input type="submit" value="create" />
```

now for some reason when I try to submit the form it returns a 403 forbidden because "CSRF token missing or incorrect.". I don't get why this is not working and its getting really frustrating.

Comment: You have the csrf middleware loaded? django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware

Comment: middleWare is already there in the settings.py @professorDante

Answer (score 1):

Use `render` instead of `render_to_response` so that the request is included in the template context.

```
return render(request, 'trial1/library_form.html', {'formset': formset})
```

Comment: already tried that. it only worked in the end when I removed 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' from settings.py. Dont know if that would have any side effects

Comment: Don't remove the middleware -  that leaves your site's users vulnerable to csrf attacks. What is the value of your template context processors setting?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the RequestContext object. The CSRF token is added by the CsrfMiddleware to the RequestContext object. When you do not include the object, the token will be empty (inspect the form element in your browser and you will see it is missing).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext

Use the `render` method or add the RequestContext to your view

```
 return render_to_response('trial1/library_form.html',
                          {'formset': formset},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response (see `context_instance` attribute)